# Finding file names without a specified character

Tags: regex, linux, file, unix, sed

Is there a good `regex` to find all of the files that **do not** contain a certain character?  I know there are lots to find lines containing matches, but I want something that will find all files that **do not** contain my match.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ls` and `sed` to replace all filenames with no extension (i.e. not containing a `.`) with `NoExtension`:

```
ls | sed -e 's/^[^.]*$/NoExtension/g'
```

replacing filenames that have an extension with their extension:

```
ls | sed -e 's/^[^.]*$/NoExtension/g' -e 's/.*\.\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Append `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` to the last command to get a sorted count. A shorter sed alternative: `/\./! s/$/.NoExtension/; s/.*\.//`.

Answer (score 1):

for bash - to list all files in a directory-:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*.*)
```

The extglob setting is required to enable to ! which negates the *.* argument to ls.

Comment: Without `ls`, create an array: `no_ext_files=(!(*.*)); num="${#no_ext_files[@]}"`

Comment: @suspectus: I think your solution (including **ls**) doesn't work if the directory has subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You should discard all the answers that parse the output of `ls` read [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for why. The tool `find` is perfect for this.

```
# Show files in cwd
$ ls
file  file.txt

# Find the files with an extension 
$ find -type f  -regex '.*/.*\..*$'
./file.txt

# Invert the match using the -not option
$ find -type f  -not -regex '.*/.*\..*$'
./file
```

Answer (score 0):

And an awk solution, for good measure.

```
ls | awk '$0 !~ /\..+$/{a++}END{print a}'
```

Comment: This prints the counts not the files name should be  `ls | awk '!/\..+$/'` but you don't want to parse the output of `ls` altogether.

Comment: My awk script (the count) matches his brief (counting files w/o an extension in a directory) before the edit: count files. For the task at hand **ls** is perfectly adequate, I'm not parsing anything other than the file-names.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (find, GNU sed & wc):

```
find . -type f | sed -rn '\|.*/\.?[^.]+$|w NoExtensions' && wc -l NoExtensions
```

This gives you a count and a list.

N.B. `dot` files without extensions are included.